# Modify Python Path for Python3 only

Tags: python, linux, centos5, python-3.2

I am developing in both Python 3 and Python 2.6, and have both versions installed.  With Python 3, however, the path to lots of the good modules (time, math, ...) is not part of my Python path.  I can add the directory to the path, but it's tedious.

Is there a way to permanently modify the path for my Python 3 installation without affecting Python 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create virtual environment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/

Install packages you want in virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't import time, math modules that are in stdlib then your installation of Python 3 is broken.

When you run `python setup.py install` the files are installed in correct place for current python executable be it a system python or python from a virtualenv environment. The same goes for `pip`.

You don't need to modify any paths, just use an appropriate executables.